# How to insert HTML elements inside a Tooltip Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip

I have a piece of code to generate a tootip using bootstrap.

```
var msg ="Oops! This is a test message";
$('#addItInfo').attr('data-original-title',msg);
$('#addItInfo').tooltip('show');
setTimeout( function(){ 
   $('#addItInfo').tooltip('hide');
   $('#addItInfo').removeAttr('title');
   $('#addItInfo').removeAttr('data-original-title'); 
}  , 2500 ); //Wait 2,5 seconds
```

This code works good, but imagine that instead of a simply message I want tho display a table with some data. I've try to create a `<table>` element inside the `var msg` like this:

```
var msg ="<table><tr><td>January</td><td>$100</td></tr><tr><td>February</td><td>$50</td></tr></table>";
```

I was expecting to see a table inside the tootip but what I got was the string `<table><tr><td>January</td><td>$100</td></tr><tr><td>February</td><td>$50</td></tr></table>`.

Here in this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/uwsrto6r/1/) I am using the same idea but without bootstrap. It works, with some minors issues, that I can solve later.

For now my question is how to allow bootstrap to display any HTML element inside the tooltip? I took a look at the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips), but I found nothing related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `data-html="true"` on the trigger element. Its is documented.

> Html option - defaults to false. Insert HTML into the tooltip.  If false, jQuery's text method will be used to insert content into the
>   DOM. Use text if you're worried about XSS attacks.

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44khF/1131/)

Comment: It is true ... I missed this line!